# Python: function to identify all subfolders that match a pattern

Tags: python, regex, grep, directory

I have written the following bit of code to find all subfolders matching a certain pattern.  However I do not have a way of checking that this function actually is finding all matches.

I want to retrieve all folders that have a name of the form "19xx@60xx_npo" where xx are characters, possibly uppercase.

```
def findWrongEncut(path):
    pathList = glob.glob("./%s/19*@60*_npo" %path)
    print pathList
    print len(pathList)
```

Does the function above guarantee that I will get all folders that match "19xx@60xx_npo"

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider using `os.path.join` instead of string interpolation to prepend `path` to the glob.

Comment: Update: since this was written python came out with PEP428. I recommend people doing things with paths learn about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it will also match things that are not directories and names like '19xxxxxx@60xxxxxxxx_npo'. If you want to match a specific number of letters, use `?` for each character in your glob. If you want to guarantee directories, throw a trailing slash on the glob expression:

```
pathList = glob.glob("./%s/19??@60??_npo/" % path)
```

Comment: lol you answered so fast i'm not allowed to accept it yet!  Thanks!

Comment: @olliepower take your time accepting. Maybe someone else knows a better answer. Give it 24 hours so the whole world gets a chance to see your question.